# How to handle ':' in command using os.popen

Tags: python, pipe, popen

I am trying to call a program with:

```
os.popen("program -s:'*' -c:'A;B;C;'")
```

However, it seems that it was interpreted as shell command:

```
program -s '*' -c 'A;B;C;'
```

which result incorrect behavior.

Can somebody help me on how to hanle such situdations where ':' is inside shell commandline?

Comment: Why not use the `subprocess` module instead? `os.popen()` is rather low level.

Comment: I wrote a small C program that just prints whatever arguments are given on the command line and substituted it for `program` in your example, and it just prints two arguments: `-s:'*'` and `-c:'A;B;C;` -- I don't think whatever incorrect behavior you're experiencing is Python's fault here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `os.popen()`, use the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.check_output(['program', "-s:'*'", "-c:'A;B;C;'"])
```

This returns the output of the program without running it through a shell, passing in the arguments directly without any additional parsing.

Comment: Hi, I did try to use subprocess.popen, the result is the same. I typed popen because it is shorter

Comment: @Yi.He Did you pass `shell=True`? If you did, remove that and try again.

Comment: @Yi.He: then *the program* is the issue here, not the shell or Python, as Mauris' test already pointed out.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem lies on shell=True